# SQL Server update statement using a join on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having some trouble here.

Table 1:

```
CID, Name, HID
(001-233, Test1, 12345)
```

Table 2:

```
CID, Name, HID, Primary
(001-233, Test1, 12345, '')
```

Want to update `Table2` where a join exists with `Table1` with a constant value called `'Y'`

So statement is as follows:

```
UPDATE T2 SET T2.Primary = 'Y'
FROM T2 
INNER JOIN T1 
    ON (T1.CID = T2.CID 
        AND T1.HID = T2.HID)
```

This statement just ends up updating all the rows, it's like it only does a join on one id and not the other? I finally gave up and did a `WHERE IN` subquery with a single "id" by concatenating the two ide fields CID+HID.  But I want to understand why this didnt work using the proper join.

`Table1` is a CTE..

Comment: This should work, could you add some example data that you would expect not to be updated?

Comment: That works for me.  I imagine it updates all rows because there are matching rows in T1 for every row of T2.

Comment: Doesnt work, T1 is a CTE.  I dont get this its driving me crazy.  It works the other way I just dont get it.

Comment: @sridawg: Can you put the query as it is including CTE ?

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a98ce/9

Comment: You should show us both querys, including the definition of your CTE

Answer (score 0):

```
update t2 
set (t2.primary) = (select 'Y' from t1 where T1.CID = T2.CID AND T1.HID = T2.HID)
```

Comment: thanks, but i want to know why the traditional join isn't working i already said i got it working through that workaround